# Line chart symbols clipped by axis when they lie on the axis

Tags: java, charts, javafx

I have a line chart with a defined axis range, and am plotting points as part of the line that lie on the axis. By default the points and the line segments that lie on the axis are clipped, as shown in the below screen shot;

[image]

My code is as below;

```
package com.jtech;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShowSymbol extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,4,1);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,10,2);

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

    final XYChart.Data d1 = new XYChart.Data(0.0, 0.0);
    final XYChart.Data d2 = new XYChart.Data(0.5, 2.0);
    final XYChart.Data d3 = new XYChart.Data(1.0, 2.5);
    final XYChart.Data d4 = new XYChart.Data(1.5, 3.5);
    final XYChart.Data d5 = new XYChart.Data(2.0, 10.0);
    final XYChart.Data d6 = new XYChart.Data(2.5, 10.0);
    final XYChart.Data d7 = new XYChart.Data(3.0, 0.0);
    final XYChart.Data d8 = new XYChart.Data(3.5, 0.0);
    final XYChart.Data d9 = new XYChart.Data(4.0, 8.0);

        series.getData().addAll(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 400, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/show.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

where the style sheet contains;

```
.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: grey; -fx-stroke-width: 4.0px; -fx-effect: null; }

.chart-line-symbol {
     -fx-background-color: #860061, white;
     -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
     -fx-background-radius: 0;
     -fx-padding: 4px;
 }
```

I would like to keep the axis range as specified (0->4 and 0->10), but show the complete segments of the symbols and lines that lie on them. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not simply use `new NumberAxis(0,4.2,1)` and `new NumberAxis(0,10.2,2)`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic The issue is more relevant to the zero axis i.e. see the point plotted on the origin in the example. If I use new NumberAxis(-0.2,4.2,1) for instance, the tick marks will start at -0.2, and the graph looks pretty ugly. AFAIK there is no mechanism to set the range to start at -0.2, but the first tick mark at 0 which is what I want it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the plot area is clipped. Code excerpt from XYChart.java:

```
private final Group plotArea = new Group(){
  @Override public void requestLayout() {} // suppress layout requests
};
private final Group plotContent = new Group();
private final Rectangle plotAreaClip = new Rectangle();

public XYChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis) {
...
getChartChildren().addAll(plotBackground,plotArea,xAxis,yAxis);
...
plotArea.setClip(plotAreaClip);
...
}
```

A solution might be to simply disable the clip. But that most probably will give you other troubles (line overlapping, etc). Nontheless, since there is no proper API for this, here's a quick & dirty way about how you could disable the clipping:

```
Region chartContent = (Region) lineChart.lookup(".chart-content");
for( Node node: chartContent.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
    if( node instanceof Group) {
        Group plotArea= (Group) node;
        plotArea.setClip(null);
    }
}
```

It'll look like this then:

[image]

Bottom line: You're better off with implementing your own chart (e. g. use and change the source of LineChart and XYChart) that supports this feature. Or you [file a change request](http://bugreport.java.com/) for a proper solution.